# Reports missing on SonarQube dashboard after upgrade

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

Recently I've upgraded SonarQube from 3.5 to 4.5.4 (LTS) and now there are a few users complaining that there are some reports missing on their project dashboards. The reports/numbers missing widgets are: *lines of code* and *complexity*. Unit tests coverage displays nothing. Other widgets (like technical debt, issues, directory tangle index) display 0 which also is suspicious. The project is in Java using the Sonar way profile.

The user does:

```
mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.login=login -Dsonar.password=***** -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.prefsize=0 -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3600000
```

The `sonar:sonar` step shows "0 files indexed".

The log is huge so I don't want to paste it here. I could not find anything helpful in it. What do I need to do to have all reports I used to have?
I have a test project where most of the missing data is displayed "out of the box".

Answer (score 2):

Starting with version 4.3, [SonarQube no longer runs automated tests](http://www.sonarqube.org/unit-test-execution-in-sonarqube/).  It expects Jenkins/CI system to run the tests, create the JUnit/PMD/Jacoco/Clover etc. reports, and then tell SonarQube where to find them.  (In older versions of SonarQube, this behavior could be achieved by setting the "reuseReports" flag to true.)

If the build is not configured to generate the reports, it will need to be adjusted to do so.

Comment: Exact. Moreover the log "0 files indexed" means that the Java plugin is not installed or that the path to sources is badly configured.

Comment: I have found another analysis where there are no "0 files indexed" messages and the user is using "mvn clean org.jacoco:jacoco-maven-plugin:prepare-agent install -Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true" command and still "Unit tests coverage" shows "-". The rest shows:

Unit test success 100,0%
failures 0
errors 0
tests 1 681
skipped 3
Execution Time 12 sec

Why is that? Also as I mentioned in my beginning post users do the analysis according to http://www.sonarqube.org/unit-test-execution-in-sonarqube/ and still the reports are missing some data, while there are other project which show much more.

Comment: It sounds like SonarQube found the surefire (test run) reports but not the coverage (Jacoco) reports.  Ensure the jacoco reports exist where SonarQube expects to find them, or configure the location property accordingly.  Running Maven in debug mode may help you see where the issue is.  (The builds may also need to execute the `site` phase to generate the reports depending on how the POMs are configured.)